# Laravel Multi Insert issue with quotes in value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I need to insert a large set of records in to a database table. I am getting the data from a CSV file. I thought about using a multi-insert statement for good performance. So I did something similar to the following:

```
 foreach($data as $key => $value) {

   $insert[] = [
                'id' => $value->id, 'is_published' => $value->is_published,
                "first_name" => $value->first_name, "middle_name" => $value->middle_name, "last_name" => $value->last_name,
                "description" => $value->description,
                "created_at" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($value->created_at)),
                "updated_at" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($value->changed_at))
            ];
 }

 if(!empty($insert)){
     Model::insert($insert);
 }
```

But in doing so I always see the error:

> mysql server gone away error.

I have debugged it by printing the query and I observed that by doing so, Laravel doesn't take care of single quotes or double quotes in the description value, as it automatically does while usiung `$model::save();`. The printed query version breaks if the description value has single quotes `'` or double quotes `"` in it.

But if I do some thing like

```
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
   $model = new Model();
   $model->id = $value->id;
   $model->description = $value->description;
   blah blah bla

   $model->save();
}
```

It runs successfully without generating any error. Can anybody let me know how to correct this problem?

Comment: Please use laravel Transactions to insert multiple records.

Comment: @Komal And how it is related to my problem?

Comment: wierd behaviour... I'm not doing mass inserts, but I would try this: `str_replace('"','\"',$value->description)`, just an idea...

Comment: Have you tried query builder way? `DB::table('table_name')->insert($insert);`

Comment: @RaviHirani Save result with Query Builder too

Comment: What Laravel Version are you using? I might be mstaken, but the static function `insert` does not exist in Laravel 4.2 (what I'm using). I was thinking about finding the error in the Model Class:  `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php`. It looks like this insert method bypasses the SQL injection security of Laravel... Must be a bug

Comment: @EdwinKrause I am using Laravel 5.2

Comment: Last time I used Laravel (which I don't use anymore because as soon as you try to do something out of the box like this, it gets too tricky) I ended up writing "raw" statements, and using the underlying libraries to make it safe. From memory, this article http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries is pretty close to what I remember doing - if it's still applicable, might be the way to go. If not, you can use the "PDO" part to make your own query safe.

Comment: I just tested your code and inserted single and double quotes in the text and laravel successfully parsed them.  can you show example of texts that failed and the errors?

Comment: How many data do you have? You may need to check if the sql size generated by the batch insert exceeds the query length limit of your mysql server.

Comment: It worked for me with Model::insert()  with using single and double quotes. Mysql Server gone away error also does not indicate syntax errors caused by quotes. Most likely the error is in fact caused by to big amount of data. ( If you think I am wrong please show how you debugged this query and give the exact error message )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its due to large set of data nothing wrong with quotes problem. When you are trying to insert all rows at once using multi-insert, the dataset becomes too heavy. Either you need to increase the max_allowed_packet or you need to do in chunks. 
You can use chunk for that.
suppose you want to insert 100 elements at a time. you can do something like that.

```
 if(!empty($insert))
 {

    $collection = collect($insert)->chunk(100)->toArray();

    foreach ($collection as $insert)
    {
       // It will insert 100 items at a time

        Model::insert($insert);
    }

 }
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: @AwaisQarni I think this answer actually solves the problem, as `MySQL server has gone away` error is probably caused by too long lasting query, not the quotes.

Comment: accepting this answer as correct makes the question quite worthless ( nothing wrong with the answer, this was my guess, too )

Answer (score 0):

How much records are your trying to bulk insert? 
Can you try with just two? 
Can you try to make severals bulk inserts (like 100 by 100).

Usually, the error `Mysql has gone away` means that the database server killed the query because it was waiting for too much data (your query is too big).

You can usually set a higher value to `max_allowed_packet` var in my.conf to allow you to send more data at once.